# Aggregate Data based on date difference range in Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an scenario where I need to aggregate data based on the Date difference of within two days range and aggregated date should have the oldest date as show in output.

Input Dataframe

| InputDate | Quantitiy |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-04-09 10:10:10 | 1 |
| 2019-04-11 10:10:10 | 5 |
| 2019-04-12 10:10:10 | 4 |
| 2019-04-15 10:10:10 | 5 |
| 2019-04-18 10:10:10 | 5 |
| 2019-04-20 10:10:10 | 5 |

Expected/Output Dataframe

---

| OutputDate | Quantitiy |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-04-09 10:10:10 | 6 |
| 2019-04-12 10:10:10 | 4 |
| 2019-04-15 10:10:10 | 5 |
| 2019-04-18 10:10:10 | 10 |

In the above example the input dataframe has a series of dates arranged is ascending order with quantity column. The first date is April 9th and next date is April 11 so as the date difference is within range of 2 days, this two rows should be aggregated and in output the oldest date i.e. 9th April should be appeared. Going forward the 12th April is checked against the 9th April(aggregated data) so the date difference is more than 2 days hence this row remain as it is whereas 15th April is compared with the recent oldest date i.e. 12th April and the date difference is more than 2 days this row should remains as it is, same with 18th April and then 20th April is compared with the recent oldest date i.e. 18th April which is within the Date diff range of two days hence it is aggregated with 18th April data.

So let me know how to achieve this without using for loop and any User Defined function.

Comment: Lookup "window functions", check out some examples, and, using them as a reference, come up with your own implementation. Then, if you run into problems getting it to work right, post your code here and ask for help.

Comment: Just window functions is not enough here. No reason to close

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to generate range of dates (calendar) between min and max date, then calculate groups of three consecutive dates (date diff <=2 days), then join with initial data and use calculated group for aggregation.  See comments in the code.

Also I tested version without join and generating missing dates only before group calculation, it may work more performant.
Pure Spark-SQL, no loops.

```
import  java.sql.Date

println("Initial data:")

val dF = Seq(
(Date.valueOf("2019-04-09"),    1),
(Date.valueOf("2019-04-11"),    5),
(Date.valueOf("2019-04-12"),    4),
(Date.valueOf("2019-04-15"),    5),
(Date.valueOf("2019-04-18"),    5),
(Date.valueOf("2019-04-20"),    5)
  
).toDF("InputDate","Quantity")


dF.show(100, false)
dF.createOrReplaceTempView("myData")

println("Solution using generating calendar between min/max and join:")

spark.sql(""" 
with cal as (select calDate, 
                   floor((row_number() over(order by calDate)-1)/3) groupId
               from (select explode(sequence(min(InputDate), max(InputDate))) as calDate
                       from mydata) s
            )
       select min(d.InputDate) InputDate,
              sum(d.Quantity) Quantity
         from cal c inner join myData d on c.calDate=d.InputDate
        group by c.groupId 
        order by InputDate
""").show(100, false)


println("Solution without join, generating only missing dates:")

spark.sql("""
select min(InputDate) InputDate,  sum(Quantity) Quantity
from
(
--Calculate groupId
select InputDate,  Quantity,
        floor((row_number() over(order by InputDate)-1)/3) groupId, generatedFlag
from
( --generate Date range
select date_add(InputDate,i) as InputDate, Quantity, 
       (i!=0 and datediff(next_date, inputDate)-1>0) generatedFlag
from
( --Get next_date to generate date range
select InputDate, Quantity,
       lead(InputDate,1, InputDate+1) over (order by InputDate) next_date
  from myData d  
)s lateral view posexplode(sequence(InputDate, next_date-1)) e as i,x --generate rows
)s
)s
where not generatedFlag
group by groupId
order by InputDate;
""").show(100, false)
```

**Output:**

```
Initial data:
+----------+--------+
|InputDate |Quantity|
+----------+--------+
|2019-04-09|1       |
|2019-04-11|5       |
|2019-04-12|4       |
|2019-04-15|5       |
|2019-04-18|5       |
|2019-04-20|5       |
+----------+--------+

Solution using generating calendar between min/max and join:
+----------+--------+
|InputDate |Quantity|
+----------+--------+
|2019-04-09|6       |
|2019-04-12|4       |
|2019-04-15|5       |
|2019-04-18|10      |
+----------+--------+

Solution without join:
+----------+--------+
|InputDate |Quantity|
+----------+--------+
|2019-04-09|6       |
|2019-04-12|4       |
|2019-04-15|5       |
|2019-04-18|10      |
+----------+--------+
```